# how can i solve Apple App Binary Rejected?

Tags: ios, ionic4

I deploy my app on app store ,but i have error binary rejected
   this is the error message:

```
From Apple
    2. 1 Performance: App Completeness
    Guideline 2.1 - Information Needed
    We were unable to sign in to review your beta app with the demo account information you provided.

    In order for us to continue the review, you will still need to provide a functional demo account that gives us access to all parts of your beta app so that we may fully review its content, features, and functionality. If your beta app is restricted to a specific location, you will still need to provide a whitelisted demo account that gives us access to your app. Note that providing a demo video showing your beta app in use is not enough for us to continue the review.

    Next Steps

    To help us proceed with the review of your beta app, please provide a user name and password in the Beta App Review Information section for your app in App Store Connect. Please be sure to include content in your beta app that demonstrates the features and functionality available in your app.

    To provide demo account information:

    - Log in to App Store Connect
    - Click on "My Apps"
    - Select your app
    - Select “Test Information”
    - Scroll down to “Beta App Review Information”
    - Select the "A demo account is required to use all the features of the app" box
    - Enter demo credentials in the "User name" and "Password" fields
    - Click “Save”
    - Scroll up to “Builds” section and submit a new binary for review
```

how can i solve this problem please !

Comment: The error is saying itself you need to provide your application's demo login id and password so they can review your app...

Comment: Share proper demo account information and resubmit. steps are clearly mentioned in the above message .

Comment: The step is pretty clear 'We were unable to sign in to review your beta app with the demo account information you provided.' What are you confused about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The login details you provided to apple review team is not working so please verify it first whether it is working or not.

Secondly you need to give all the required info. that can be used by the review team in review process so they can test your application and take decision for your submitted app.

Comment: Great to hear that! Cheers!!